# How can I implement Paging library 2 Boundary Callback using Coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-paging-library

I want to implement my custom PagedList.BoundaryCallback with coroutines, liveData and repository pattern using Paging Library 2, but I couldn't find a good example of integration of these libraries.

Even in [Android official samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/paging2/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/paging/pagingwithnetwork/reddit/repository/inDb/SubredditBoundaryCallback.kt), they use enqueue and callbacks to perform the API request with paging 2...

I read this Medium [post](https://medium.com/@aafonsolbalves/pagedlist-boundarycallback-applying-single-source-of-truth-concept-in-kotlin-a33a96a19c71) also but it use a coroutines scope inside the boundary callback and I think that is not a good practice.

Is there any way to achieve it? Or should I migrate to Paging 3?

Comment: You can use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` or `suspendCoroutine` to convert `enqueue` calls into suspend functions. And you can use `callbackFlow` to convert callbacks that get called repeatedly into Flows that you can collect in coroutines. I don't use Paging so can't write a proper answer. The above should be enough for you to Google some examples of how to do these conversions. Though if you're going through the trouble of migrating to coroutines, I don't see why you wouldn't migrate to the latest paging library as well.

Comment: I don't know much about the specific paging library, but it's clearly stated on the version 3 that they added first class support for Kotlin coroutines, so I would honestly go for upgrading if that's an option for you. If not, then yes you can use the techniques mentioned by @Tenfour04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me:

1. I injected a CoroutinesDispatcherProvider in my Repository:

   ```
   class MyRepository @Inject constructor(
       private val remoteDataSource: MyRemoteDataSource,
       private val localDataSource: MyDao,
       private val coroutinesDispatcherProvider: CoroutinesDispatcherProvider
    ) {...}
   ```
2. Then inside my repository, I passed this provider to my boundary callback:

   ```
   private val boundaryCallback =
       MyBoundaryCallback(remoteDataSource, localDataSource, coroutinesDispatcherProvider)

   fun getList(): LiveData<PagedList<MyModel>> = LivePagedListBuilder(
       localDataSource.getAll(),
       pagedListConfig
   ).setBoundaryCallback(boundaryCallback).build()
   ```
3. And finally, I use this dispatcher in my boundary implementation to launch my request from repository:

   ```
   private val ioCoroutineScope by lazy {
      CoroutineScope(coroutinesDispatcherProvider.io)
   }

   override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
       ioCoroutineScope.launch {
           remoteDataSource.getList()
       }
   }
   ```